# How to add other languages' localization for ios app description

Tags: ios, xamarin, localization, app-store, app-store-connect

On App Store Connect, in Localizable Information of App Information of my APP, the drop down list of languages shows English(U.S.) only, I can't choose and add other languages to localize app name or app description. Does anybody know the reason? Thanks.

Not sure if this helps, my project is using Xamarin Forms, and I already added [language].lproj folder and InfoPlish.strings file. I could search my app's English name on App Store, after installed, it'll show other language's app name if changed my iphone to that language.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that same dropdown menu, you are able to select a new localization for your app but this is only possible when you are doing a new submission (your submission is in Edit mode).

The image below shows the different localization options I have available for an app that is ready to be submitted for review.

[image]

Hope this helps.-